# Can't query .INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES on BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I get this error message even tho I'm literally using the code from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables).
[image]

Comment: Too many dots, maximum are two dots before  INFORMATION_SCHEMA `[PROJECT_ID.]DATASET_ID.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Also make us of the backticks to ensure the `-` in the project_id is not the issue. Please write your query in the question, tell what are your dataset name etc.

Comment: Sorry I'm not I get what you mean, I got the example query from the google docs, I've not added any dots. Here's the query it's also in the screenshot
'SELECT * FROM uat-prod.retailer.master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;'

Answer (score 0):

This query is wrong

```
SELECT * FROM uat-prod.retailer.master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

You can query the table by

```
SELECT * FROM uat-prod.retailer.master
```

given that `uat-prod` is the project id, `retailer` is the dataset and `master` is the table in the dataset.

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is only available in the region/zone or in each dataset.
Thus your query must be:

```
SELECT * FROM uat-prod.retailer.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name ='master'
```